# Strange bug with mysql encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have an osTube site. All files saved in UTF-8. All tables created with utf8 utf8_unicode_ci, and all fields have same charset.

At connect DB function added:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this -> connection);
```

Content at the site is russian and ukrainian. When I open it, I have no any problem. Problems begin when I try use caseless regular expression - it doesn't work.

I find that, Zend Debugger show variables content not readable, but debug encoding is UTF-8. If I delete line:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this -> connection);
```

At the site I see not readable text, but if I set at the browser Windows-1251 encoding - text begin readable. And Zend Debugger show normal text, and regexp begin work. But in the browser I see only '?????'.

What is this?

Comment: `Problems begin when I try use caseless regular expression - it doesn't work.` - how do you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not clear about where you're using regular expressions? In PHP, you can enable UTF-8 support for the preg extension, using the `u` modifier.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php